# Keeping track of and canceling previous task's CancellationTokens when new queued task is executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am requesting a code review of the following, this is out of my usual area and I would like to know if the algorithm is sound? Its purpose is to keep track of the cancellation tokens of Tasks that are added to the background work queue. It should first call cancel on all existing tokens, add its own token to ConcurrentBag, and then perform work. Thanks!!

Edit: Basically I'm asking is it correct? Will newer tasks executing in this method (in the `while`) cancel older tasks that may have gotten suspended at `// Rehydrate an individual cache item` network request thus preventing unneeded work? `// Rehydrate a cache item that is a collection` only needs to be run once by the newest executing task (not every executing task)

```
public class Manager {

    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<CancellationToken> CancelTokens = new ConcurrentBag<CancellationToken>();

    // Below method gets called like this
    // HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (cancelationToken) => await PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks(cancelationToken));

    public async Task PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            // Cancel all previous tasks
            while (!CancelTokens.IsEmpty)
            {
                CancellationToken previousTaskCancelToken;
                CancelTokens.TryTake(out previousTaskCancelToken);
                if (previousTaskCancelToken.CanBeCanceled)
                {
                    CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(previousTaskCancelToken).Cancel();
                }
            }
            CancelTokens.Add(ct); // Add this task's CancellationToken to ConcurrentBag

            // Rehydrate an individual cache item

            // Only the newest task needs to run this, for performance
            if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Rehydrate a cache item that is a collection
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            TelemetryManager.TrackException("Error in PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working to me after modifying the `PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks` method to take `CancellationTokenSource` instead of `CancellationToken`. Stacked up calls do get cancelled.

```
    public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Test
        //
        // Out:
        //  Thread [852] performed the work
        //  Was last executing thread: FALSE. Was #897
        //  QueueUserWorkItem Call 1762
        //  Thread [854] performed the work
        //  Was last executing thread: FALSE. Was #1412
        //  QueueUserWorkItem Call 1391
        //  Thread [1836] performed the work
        //  Was last executing thread: TRUE. Was #2000
        //  QueueUserWorkItem Call 1984
        //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        Manager mgr = new Manager();

        // 2000 rapid updates 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((id) => {
                // Thread.Sleep(2000 - (int) id);
                Random rand = new Random();
                Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(2, 500));
                CancellationTokenSource ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async (state) => await mgr.PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks(ctSource, (int) id, rand.Next(7, 2500)));
            })).Start(i);
        };
        Task.Delay(15000).Wait(); // Keep ThreadPool alive
    }
}

public class Manager
{

    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<CancellationTokenSource> CancelTokens = new ConcurrentBag<CancellationTokenSource>();
    private static volatile int AtomicCounter = 0;

    // Below method gets called like this
    // HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (cancelationToken) => await PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks(cancelationToken));

    public async Task PerformTaskAndCancelPreviousTasks(CancellationTokenSource cts, int tN, int delay)
    {
        try
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref AtomicCounter);
            // Cancel all previous tasks
            while (!CancelTokens.IsEmpty)
            {
                CancellationTokenSource previousTaskCancelTokenSource = null;
                CancelTokens.TryTake(out previousTaskCancelTokenSource);
                if (previousTaskCancelTokenSource != null)
                {
                    previousTaskCancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }
            CancelTokens.Add(cts); // Add this task's CancellationToken to ConcurrentBag

            await Task.Delay(delay); // Simulate network request

            // Only the newest task needs to run this, for performance
            if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Rehydrate a cache item that is a collection
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread [{0}] performed the work", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Was last executing thread: {0}. Was #{1}", AtomicCounter == 2000 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE", AtomicCounter));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("QueueUserWorkItem Call {0}", tN));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred in:\r\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```